# PL/SQL Switch from case statements to calculate a date based on a custom calendar by joining two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, sas

I would like to replace the existing lengthy set of CASE...WHEN statements to create a date field based on a custom calendar in an existing script.

```
SELECT 
F.SKU,
case
    when TRUNC (F.WEEK_ENDING) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-04-2020') and TO_DATE('01-25-2020') then 'Jan 2020'
    when TRUNC (F.WEEK_ENDING) BETWEEN TO_DATE('02-01-2020') and TO_DATE('02-22-2020') then 'Feb 2020'
 end AS Period 
From data_table F;
```

A calendar table has been created with start_date, end_date, month, year and month_name.
[image: Calendar Table]

My question is how do I link these tables so that each F.Week_Ending date is checked against all the start and end dates in the calendar table to determine the period?

Can this be done within the Select query,  I have to embed this script in SAS as a Proc SQL, so not sure if I can run a function in there?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a join:

```
select 
    f.sku,
    c.period_name
from data_table f
inner join calendar_table c 
    on f.week_ending between c.start_date and c.end_date
```

Depending on how you define your intervals, you might need the following join condition:

```
    on trunc(f.week_ending) between c.start_date and c.end_date
```

However, keep in mind that such an expression defeats an existing index on `(data_table(week_ending)`, so this is not a good practice. Ideally, you should be using half-open intervals in the calendar table, ie define *including* starting date and *excluding* end dates, so you can safely do:

```
    on f.week_ending >= c.start_date and f.week_ending < c.end_date
```

Comment: Thank You! That was a stupid question from me in hindsight. Thanks for the prompt reply.